# Como deseleccionar dinamicamente un checkbox generado con cakePHP utilizando javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, cakephp

Buenas amigos estoy atrapado en un problema que no puedo resolver. Estoy generando un checkbox con cakePHP v 2.0. EN la parte de arriba he generado un input del tipo date para poder ajustar la fecha. Cuando esta fecha es mayor a 3 anios el checkbox se deshabilita, todo correcto hasta el momento. El problema radica cuando uno pone  una fecha menor a los 3 anios , selecciona el checkbox y digamos que vuelves a cambiar la fecha por una mayor a 3 anios. logro que el checkbox se deshabilite pero no que se deseleccione. Les comparto una parte del codigo.

```
                        'type' => 'checkbox', 
                        'before' => false,
                        'between' => false,
                        'after' => false,
                    ));

        var differenceDatesMiliseconds = purchasedDate - announcedDate;
        var differenceInYears = differenceDatesMiliseconds / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        differenceInYears = Math.abs(Math.floor(differenceInYears));

        if (differenceInYears > 3) {

            warrantyCheckbox.checked = false;
            warrantyCheckboxHidden.checked = false;
            warrantyFirmDropdown.style.display = 'none';
          }
```

Comment: Con el código que has mostrado no es posible responderte, `.checked=false` debería bastar para deshabilitar el checkbox. Te aconsejo que pongas el código HTML generado en tu pregunta. Con html generado me refiero al html que muestra el navegador, no al código PHP.